# Why don't downloads switch back to wifi after been on a cellular network?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, alamofire

I have encountered a rather strange behavior when trying to implement download functionality on iOS. The download implementation works fine in that it finishes successfully, can run in the background, and file is stored on device. However during a download, I can turn of wifi to let the task switch to and continue on cellular network (or just start the download using cellular). This behaves as aspected. But when I enable wifi again, the download never seem to switch back to using wifi. The device is connected, and the wifi-connection-bars displays at the statusbar. Using rechability functions to check what connection that is available will even return Wifi, but the download seems to be stuck at using cellular.

The way I am detecting this is looking at the Usage stats in the system settings. The cellular data usage will rise in sync with the pending download, and continue to rise until the download is finished (even if wifi is turned on again).

I have tested with both Alamofire and by using NSURLSession and NSURLSessionDownloadTask directly, and they both behaves similarly. I have also seen this behavior in two completely seperate projects, on multiple devices, in iOS 8.4 and 9.1, when the apps are in the foreground or the background, and even AppStore behaves like this when downloading apps!

Has somebody else experienced this?
And if so, did you find any way to gracefully switch tasks back to wifi?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior.  Adding a new network interface (e.g. turning Wi-Fi on) doesn't stop existing TCP connections.  They will continue until the original network interface goes away.

If you want to pause the request and reconnect when Wi-Fi becomes available, you'll need to call cancelByProducingResumeData: on the task, then create a new request with that resume data to restart the request from where it left off.  That new request will go over the currently active network interface, which would typically be the Wi-Fi interface if Wi-Fi is up and running.

Before you stop the existing request, though, I would suggest trying a probe request for something like Google's generate 204 or one of Apple's captive portal detection URLs, to ensure that Wi-Fi really is working.